# do.call and curve can not plot a function inside another function environment

Tags: r, curve, do.call

I am facing a strange problem about **do.call** and **curve**:

```
func1 <- function (m, n) {
  charac <- paste ("func2 <- function(x)", m, "*x^", n, sep = "")
  eval(parse(text = charac))
  return(func2)
}
func3 <- function (m, n) {
  my.func <- func1 (m, n)
  do.call("curve",list(expr = substitute(my.func)))
}
```

**func1** constructs **func2** and **func3** plots the constructed **func2**.
But when I run **func3**, following error would be displayed:

```
> func3 (3, 6)
Error in curve(expr = function (x)  : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

However, while I run **func1** and plot the output manually (without applying **func3**),  **func2 would be plotted**:

```
my.func <- func1 (3, 6)
do.call("curve",list(expr = substitute(my.func)))
```

What happened here leads me to a confusion and I do not know why **do.call** can not plot **func2** inside **func3** local environment.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem of `do.call`, but  `substitute` <s>which evaluate by default in the global environment.
So</s> you need to tell it in which environment substitution must occur. Here obviously in the local envir of func3.

This should work:

```
 do.call("curve",list(expr = substitute(my.func,
                                           env = parent.frame())))
```

**Edit** thanks Dwin

As said in the comment substitute env  Defaults to the current evaluation environment. So Why the code below works? The answer in the help of `substitute`

> formal argument to a function or explicitly created using
>   delayedAssign(), the expression slot of the promise replaces the
>   symbol. If it is an ordinary variable, its value is substituted,
>   unless env is .GlobalEnv in which case the symbol is left unchanged.

`env = parent.frame(n=1)` is equivalent to `.GlobalEnv`, that why the  symbol (my.func) is left unchanged. So the correct answer would be :

```
do.call("curve",list(expr = substitute(my.func,
                                               env = .GlobalEnv)))
```

To test , I open new R session :

```
func1 <- function (m, n) {
  charac <- paste ("func2 <- function(x)", m, "*x^", n, sep = "")
  eval(parse(text = charac))
  return(func2)
}
func3 <- function (m, n) {
  my.func <- func1 (m, n)

  do.call("curve",list(expr = substitute(my.func,env = .GlobalEnv)))
}
```

Than I call

```
 func3(2,6)
```

Comment: @EhsanMasoudi if it works and you are satisfied of the question you can accept it by checking the box at left.

Comment: The help page for `substitute` says it is evaluated in the current environment.

Comment: Can you please create a context where this code doesn't throw an error? I get "could not find function 'my.curve"

Comment: Not with the new code, but when the first argument to `do.call` is "my.curve" it provokes an error.

Comment: @DWin oops...corrected! I hacked `curve` function and I forget to remove the name. thank's for your help.

Comment: Or just use a closure: `func2 <- function(x) x * m ^ n`

Comment: `substitute` doesn't _evaluate_ anything

Answer (score 3):

You are making this overcomplicated - you don't need to do anything special when creating `f2`:

```
f1 <- function (m, n) {
  function(x) m * x ^ n
}
f3 <- function (m, n) {
  f2 <- f1(m, n)
  curve(f2)
}
f3(3, 6)
```

This could, of course, be made more concise by eliminating `f1`:

```
f4 <- function (m, n) {
  f2 <- function(x) m * x ^ n
  curve(f2)
}
f4(3, 6)
```

You can find more information about R's scoping rules (which makes this work) at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functions

Comment: ++ :(more for the link than for the answer) I thought the question was how to pass arguments to functions that take expression arguments using `do.call` inside another function, but maybe I was over-reading it. Reading you material I wonder if the problem might be that what was being passed was a closure rather than a function?

Comment: @DWin all functions are closures, so that's probably not the problem.  But I don't really understand what you're trying to do in your answer.   You might also find https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Computing-on-the-language helpful, but it's still pretty rough. https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/R/draw-tree.r is also useful.

Comment: @hadley Yes I made it complicated, but it was just an simplified example of my main code. as you know R has no ability to handle symbolic computation (however there is a package called Ryacas and it's an interface to yacas). In my code such this method is applied to auto-construct Fisher information matrix for nonlinear models without user interfere

Comment: @EhsanMasoudi R does have extensive capabilities for symbolic computation.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
func3 <- function (m, n) {
   my.func <- func1 (m, n); print(str(my.func))
   do.call(curve, list(expr=bquote( my.func) ) )
 }
```

Comment: Can't tell why there's output with this method, though.

Comment: `curve` is supposed to accept a function, so I don't understand your lack of understanding.

Comment: sorry, I'm not talking about the plot, I'm talking about the jibberish that prints to screen.

Comment: Sorry. That print() call was just my way of making sure that `my.func` was really a function at that point. It can safely be ignored or removed.

Answer (score -2):

You just need to remove line:

my.func <- func1 (m, n)

from func3.

Comment: How can that possibly help?